# Leer archivos especiales CSV con formato español

Tags: csv, read

Tengo un archivo descargado del Ministerio de Industria, Comercio y Turismo de España, el cual viene en formato csv, que Excel identifica como separador el tabulador.  He tratado de cargarlo con el siguiente código:

```
df= pd.read_csv("C:XXX/TARIC.csv", delimiter:'\t', encoding='latin-1'
```

La línea corre bien, el resultado es el equivocado.  Solo despliega NAN.

El archivo seguro (descargado del Gobierno de España) es el siguiente:  https://we.tl/t-FiAo2xAZuP

Es identificado como UNICODE.

Si no pueden descargar el archivo, adjunto una muestra:

```
  df2= {'cod_taric':['00', '0090', '009000', '0101109000'], 'nivel_taric':[1, 2, 3, 5], 'taric':['COMERCIO, CONFIDENCIAL', 'Comercio, de bienes y servicios', 'Comercio, servicios, transporte', 'Asnos, mulos y burdéganos vivos, reproductores raza pura']}
  
df3=pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, por favor agrega algunas líneas del archivo CSV como texto en tu pregunta, el URL que provees requiere registrarse.

Answer (score 0):

El código que funcionó para leer usa el encoding UTF-16 y no el latin-1:

taric=pd.read_csv("TARIC.csv", sep="\t",encoding='UTF-16')

Algo que me ha ayudado para este tipo de archivos es usar la librería chardet que ayuda a identificar el enconding:

```
import chardet

with open(r"XXXTARIC.csv", 'rb') as rawdata:
    result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(10000))

print(result)

{'encoding': 'UTF-16', 'confidence': 1.0, 'language': ''}
```